# Variable value is reset inside a loop in C

Tags: c, loops, zero

I have a case in which I have to identify if a number is positive, negative or zero and count how many times each of these cases happen. The code I wrote is this:

```
#include 
#include 
#include 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char opcion = 's';
    int positivos = 0;
    int negativos = 0;
    int ceros = 0;
    //int ceros2 = 0;
    int temporal;
    do{
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&temporal);
        if(temporal >= 0)
        {
            if(temporal==0)
            { 
                ceros ++;
            }
            else
            {
                positivos ++;
            }
        }

        if(temporal < 0)
        { 
            negativos ++;
        }
        printf("Do you want to enter another number? (s/n)");
        scanf("%s",&opcion);
    }
    while(opcion == 's' || opcion=='S');
    printf("you have %d possitive numbers \n",positivos);
    printf("you have %d negative numbers \n",negativos);
    printf("you have %d zero \n",ceros);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the code as it is, the number of zeroes will always be zero, but if you uncoment the line 13 `int ceros2 = 0;` (my logic was "let's declare another initializaed variable and see what happens") then the program will count the zeroes as expected. Why do i have to declare a useless variable in order to the program make the count?

What is C compiler doing with the code that does not respect the value of the last declared and initialized variable unless you declare a new initialized variable?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&opcion);` to get one character? Nope. `%s` is is for a string. This is undefined behavior and could explain what you are seeing...

Comment: `using namespace std;` oops, your program is in [tag:c++]!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking `scanf()` to read in a C string, which, if the user types a character, will contain both that character and the null terminator. You have provided only a single character's worth of storage. So, the null terminator doesn't fit but it gets stored somewhere. As it happens, it's clobbering other data that happens to be next to `opcion` on the stack and that happens to be your `ceros` variable.

Declaring another variable has reorganized the layout of data on the stack and changes what gets clobbered, so you're not noticing it. It's still writing out of bounds, though.

You could use a format string of `"%c"` to read a single character.